# Visual Studio Express 2015 a setup package is either missing or damaged

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I deleted VS Express 2015 and tried to re-install.
I got this message.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zawB.jpg)

Anyone knows the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get some help from this [MSDN Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2015/07/17/removing-visual-studio-components-left-behind-after-an-uninstall.aspx)

Your image description says about a missing file, So you can repair Visual Studio and then You will be able to uninstall it.